# "Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test" when testing a function that returns a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js

I wrote a very simple function that returns a promise. When the promise resolves it returns all the trip objects from the database. When I console.log the result in a then function, I see all the objects, so I know the function works. But when I try to test it, I get this "timeout" exception. I wrote another function that returns a simple promise object with omitting all mongoose and database connection objects and it threw the same error. I think it is about resolving promises in mocha an not about mongoose or database connection.

Can anyone help me find what is wrong here or how should i keep investigating the problem?

Thanks in advance.

in the processRoutes.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('../models/Trip');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/gtfs-dev');
var mongodb = mongoose.connection;

var Trip = mongodb.model('Trip');

var findTrips = function () {
    var query = Trip.find({},{"trip_id":1, "_id":0});
    var promise = query.exec();
    return promise;
}
```

processRoutes.spec.js:

```
...    
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

    var processroutes = require('./processRoutes');

    describe('ProcessRoute', function () {

        it('dependencies should exist', function () {
            expect(processroutes).to.be.not.undefined;
        });

        describe('#findTrips()', function(){

            it('should exist and be a function', function(){
                expect(processroutes.findTrips).to.be.not.null;
                expect(processroutes.findTrips).to.be.a('function');
            });

            it('should return a promise', function(){
                var promise = processroutes.findTrips();
                expect(promise).to.be.a('promise');
            });

            it('should resolve to an array', function(){
                return processroutes.findTrips().then(function(trips){
                     expect(trips).to.be.instanceof(Array);
                });
            });

        });

    });
```

The result of the tests is like this:

```
 ProcessRoute
    ✓ dependencies should exist
    #findTrips()
      ✓ should exist and be a function
      ✓ should return a promise
      1) should resolve to an array


  3 passing (5s)
  1 failing

  1) ProcessRoute #findTrips() should resolve to an array:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Comment: Is it possible it is just taking more than 2 seconds? If you increase the timeout, does the problem disappear?

Comment: @melis Try `return processroutes.findTrips().to.eventually.equal(<array object>);`

Comment: @thefourtheye  which library I need to import for using "eventually" ?

Comment: @Louis, I tried adding `this.timeout(10000);` in the describe suit and the test passed with the following:       ✓ should resolve to an array (9492ms)
9492 ms? When I output the result of the function, I see it the result much sooner that the promise resolves in the mocha test. Do you have any idea why it might be happening?

Comment: How do you "output the result of the function"? I'm thinking you are not looking at the right thing.

Comment: If you return the promise in your second test does it pass without a `timeout` tweak?

Comment: @MarcoL, i changed the second test to -> it('should return a promise', function(){ return processroutes.findTrips();}); and the test results are:       ✓ should return a promise (4379ms)
      ✓ should resolve to an array (5259ms)
My timeout is set to 15000 ms currently. Does this answer to your question?

Comment: 5 seconds for a query? It sounds like a lot. Probably you want to mock your db service for testing.

Comment: @Louis, to output it I change the function's .exec() with .exec(function(err, data) console.log(data.length) return data;); The test result shows ->      ✓ should return a promise 119292 ✓ should resolve to an array (9025ms). I see the number of documents about 3 seconds before I see "✓ should resolve to an array (9025ms). That delay between what confuses me.

Comment: @melis I don't know what's going on then. I've used promises extensively with Mocha and I've never seen a promise resolving mysteriously later than when it should. Maybe there's something Mongoose does that would explain it. I've certainly seen some popular libraries that had bugs in the way they managed promises.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help everyone.